# Delete all contents of the file using sed

Tags: unix, sed, empty-list

I want to empty a file using sed command. I searched lot of forums and tutorial. There is no available to delete all contents of the file. How to delete all contents of the file using sed command.

Comment: Your comments to answers tell of many, many details you don't put in the question. Please tell us that you're *really* trying to do. [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 9):

It looks like a strange request. Anyway, this is a way:

```
sed -i '/^/d' file
```

- `sed -i` does an in-place replacement.
- `/^/` matches lines, in this case all of them because `^` means "beginning of line".
- `/d` deletes them.

Or shorter ([thanks glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478253/delete-all-contents-of-the-file-using-sed/22478315?noredirect=1#comment34193894_22478315) as always):

```
sed -i d file
```

Comment: Nice to read that :) Remember you can mark either this or the other answer as accepted to show your issue is solved!

Comment: You don't need to provide an address. To delete every line: `sed d file`

Comment: Oh, wasn't aware of it. Many thanks, @glennjackman (and I also agree that the best way is to `> file`, but as the OP mentioned `sed`...).

Comment: why i cannot add a line in empty file using sed ? I tried this after emptying the file. But its not working. 
sed -i '$ a\This is test line ' test1.txt

Comment: `sed` is not the best way for that, @SmithDwayne. Instead, you can do `echo > file`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need sed for this. To empty a file:

```
> filename
```

with no command, that redirection will truncate the file.

Comment: shall i use this in c using system() function ?

Comment: what? why on earth would you not use [C functions](http://man.cx/creat)? It seems completely wasteful to launch a shell just to truncate a file.

Comment: Hi, Its not only about truncating the file. I would like to use already built unix system calls for file manipulating issues instead of writing own c code. for eg, to copy a file I just can call cp unix call using system command. I really don't know which is efficient way to do file manipulation. Now I am just practicing how this stuffs is working through 'c' programs.

Comment: I get you're learning and experimenting. However, if you want to use these shell commands, write a shell script. If you're coding in C, learn the C functions you require. It is most inefficient to spawn a shell and invoke command line commands that are themselves implemented in C. It's all open source, so find how they are implemented.

Comment: Where can i find the source code unix system calls commands. I had looked it sourceforge.net. But I can't find the solution what i have searched for. If you show me the route to find and read that codings, it would be great for my carriers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this `sed`.  It will remove all.

```
sed -ni '' file
```

`n` do not print if not told to do so.
`i` in place.
Since no code is given, file will be replaced by nothing.